# Add data using ajax in Modal asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

i have a modal with bootstrap that allow me to add some data in database using ajax..after that i load data in partial view and show it (classic)

this is my controller :

```
     public ActionResult AjouterCommentaire(TacheViewModel viewModel)
    {

        viewModel.NVcommentaire.DateCommentaire = DateTime.Now;
        viewModel.NVcommentaire.UtilisateurId = 4 ;

        db.Commentaires.Add(viewModel.NVcommentaire);
        db.SaveChanges();



        return PartialView("PartialCommentaire", db.Commentaires);
    }
```

the problem that when i return the partial view `PartialCommentaire`
that is the table with data .. the table take all the modal space it's like the modal take the table value .. (and it's logic as i return that partial view)

if i return :  `return Json(new { success = true });`  it refreshh the page, and i dont want that..

what i have to return so the only thing to change will be the partialview with the table

Think you

**Edit : (add html )**

```
      @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AjouterCommentaire", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "partialSummaryDiv" }))
      {
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
                </p>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.NVcommentaire.TxtCommentaire, new { @class = " form-control", @placeholder = "Ajouter un Commentaire", @rows = "7" })
                        </div>
      }
                        <div class="col-md-8" id="partialSummaryDiv">
                            @{ Html.RenderPartial("PartialCommentaire", Model.Commentaires); }
                        </div>


            </div>
```

**Edit2 :**
i  tried this but it still not working !!

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Tache/AjouterCommentaire",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (result) {
            // refreshes partial view
            $('#partialSummaryDiv').html(result);
        }
    });

});
```

and changed  the div to be :

```
   <div class="col-md-8" id="partialSummaryDiv">
     @{ Html.RenderPartial("PartialCommentaire", Model.Commentaires); }
```

Comment: You have to provide the javascript code that do the ajax post and the dom replacement and the html of the modal to start with.

Comment: @MenelaosVergis  Edited : (ps: i'm not using any javascript i just use ajax.beginforms and it's working  if  their is no Modal..the problem is with returning data to the model

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the Model.Commentaires object has data before you pass it to the second partial view?

Comment: the problem is not in model because all the data passes without any problem.... the problem is when the controller action return the partial view....the solution will be to change  the return type  (but i dont know what to return)

Comment: Can you put some code here? The action for partial view should return PartialViewResult

Comment: yes the action for partial view return partial view ..  but  the problem is that partial view replace the original  View in the Modal (so the table take all the place in the modal )

Comment: What about removing the RenderPartial, replacing it with an empty div and  post an ajax request to the controller action and set the content of the div to the HTML returned from the partial view?

Comment: to be honest i did not get it . i look's the same to me , because the renderpartial  return html (as i know ! )

Comment: Yes, it returns HTML, but this way you will not have a partial view inside a partial view.
The firts partial view works fine with you, and inside it you will get the HTML for the inner Partial view using Ajax request and not using RenderPartial

Comment: OK  think you i will try that and  give you my feedback

Comment: i did what  you requested  but it seems their is somthing wrong please see the updated question

Comment: In Edit2: you should remove the line :  @{ Html.RenderPartial("PartialCommentaire", Model.Commentaires); }

and also you should change the type from "POST" to "GET" as this is data retrieval not submission 

Also, I can't see any HTML element with Id = "commentaires"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106952/discussion-between-aboamin12-and-haitham-shaddad).